# VueJS not working when hosted externally

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js

I've been developing a little app in VueJS, and it seemed to be working fine while developing with a local webserver. But somehow it doesn't load at all when I deploy it to Github pages.
I've also tried deploying it on my own server, that doesn't work either.

The Javascript code executes fine, but somehow the Vue code doesn't.

[Link to the website where I've deployed it](https://teunw.github.io/GTAV-CarSearch-Vue/)

[Github repository](https://github.com/teunw/GTAV-CarSearch-Vue)

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Nope, you can check the link. Nothing

Comment: I'm not sure this was deployed correctly. It's serving script out of node_modules, which if you were using webpack I would expect to bundled? Also there is a webpack:// source in the source list, which I would not expect in a production publish.

Comment: I might need to look into deploying with Webpack then. It still doesn't solve the problem with the Javascript not executing however. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It works for me - I can switch the tabs, I can see a `test` log into the console.. I guess you've already fixed that :) It would be good if you close your question.

Comment: The problem isn't with switching tabs, and the test in the console was to see if javascript executed at all. The problem is in the view not displaying on the page itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the default vuejs/vue-router setup and you are publishing to a subfolder, in your case: `http://example.com/folder/` , vue-router has an an option to modify the [base](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#mode).

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import Router from 'vue-router'

import Home from '@/components/Home'

Vue.use(Router)

const routes = [
 { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home }
]

export default new Router({
 routes,
 mode: 'history',
 base: '/folder'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found out the problem, it has to do with routing on my specific setup.

When Vue's router has routes defined on the server, it will use the routes' path that has been given. 
My problem was using Vue router with the application being deployed in a folder.
So when you execute the app, the current path will point to [http://example.com/folder/](http://example.com/yourfolder/aroute) while your route points to [http://example.com/](http://example.com/yourfolder/aroute) in my case.

I solved the problem by defining an alternate route should another fail for some reason.

```
routes: [
    { path: '/', name: "CollectionMarker", component: CollectionMarker },
    { path: '/cars', name: "CarMarker", component: CarsComponent },
    // This is the path that you need to include, it will redirect when no route has been found
    { path: "*", redirect: "/" }
]
```